# taking the contrapositive of this statement?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Statement: If every right triangle has angle defect equal to zero then the angle defect of every triangle is equal to zero

Taking the contrapositive do i have this correct? : There exists at least one triangle whose angle defect is not zero such that not every right triangle has an angle defect equal to zero.

Answer (score 3):

You're close. It should be:

> **If** there exists at least one triangle whose angle defect is not zero **then** there exists a right triangle whose angle defect is not zero.

Answer (score 3):

You are close: but you need to replace "such that" to indicate implication: If -then...So you could correctly write:

> **If** there exists at least one triangle whose angle defect is not zero, **then** *not every* right triangle has an angle defect that is equal to zero.

since "*not every right triangle has an angle defect equal to zero*" is equivalent to "*there exists a right triangle whose angle defect is not equal to zero*".

Comment: but the contrapositive requires "then there exists a right triangle whose angle defect is not equal to zero."

Comment: one last thing. For contradiction would it be "Assume to the contrary that there exists a triangle whose angle defect is not equal to zero?"

Comment: If you were to write a proof of your original statement, using proof by contradiction, yes, exactly!

Comment: This deserves a thumbs up! +1

Comment: user60887 - does this help?